# Installing apt-get

Tags: 14.04, command-line, apt, sudo, wget

The `apt-get` command and the `sudo` command does not work for me. `which apt-get` returns nothing. I checked by bin folder to make sure, and there is no `aptget`. I however have `wget`. Can I install apt-get with `wget`? If not, how can I install it?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

of course you can do that, although it is strange that you missed that package/command ... Anyway, a manual way to do it is to download the package and to install it with dpkg, as follows:

1. grab the package from the web

   ```
    wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.0.1ubuntu2.17_amd64.deb -O apt.deb
   ```

Edit: Check for the latest source at http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/?C=M;O=D

2. install it with dpkg

   ```
    sudo dpkg -i apt.deb
   ```

2 (other). Alternative use of dkpg **without sudo** - I didn't know about these, included after comments-

```
pkexec dpkg -i apt.deb
```

if everything goes right, that should be enough.

Probably you may find that some dependencies are not satisfied, to deal with that you may need to create a folder (something like "apt-installer") and drop all the dependencies of the **apt** package there. The list of dependencies required will be shown by the dpkg output and the download process is similar to the one explained above. Last, if you don't feel confident of what you are doing, my suggestion is that you may want to do a fresh install of your system.

Cheers.

Comment: Good one, but remember he said sudo didn't work either.

Comment: If only `sudo` does not work (which should get fixed as soon as possible!), you can try to replace it with `pkexec` for the moment, i.e. `pkexec dpkg -i apt.deb`

Comment: Oh dear! it is true! haha... without the sudo package everything is supposed to have the admin level, right? if that's so the only easy way that comes to my mind is to uncompress the .deb file and locate the new files and folders manually in their destination, with their proper permissions... but I'm only guessing here, at this point my "real life" solution is a fresh install. :) Thanks Byte! I didn't know about pkexec. Editing.

Comment: If the above `wget` command gets a `404` error, try `wget http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/pool/main/a/apt/apt_1.8.2_amd64.deb -O apt.deb`

Comment: @EmreTapcı This one's also a 404

Comment: Where should this be installed into?

Answer (score 5):

Now...

```
wget http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/apt_2.1.10ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb -O apt.deb
```

In the future this will likely 404 error as well, so remove the file name `apt_2.1.10ubuntu0.2_amd64.deb -O apt.deb`

and enter just the `http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/a/apt/` part into a browser. Look for the most current version of the file, and change the path to it.

Comment: I see what you’re trying to say, but can you clean the answer up with a chronological, step-by-step process for people who have a similar problem in the future? 

Comment: Sounds clear enough