# How do I install bind on user mode linux?

Tags: apt, bind, user-mode-linux

I am trying to build a DNS simulation by using bind on several user mode linux (UML) instances on the same computer. I have UML installed and working, but I can't figure out how to install anything.

I set up UML with [this tutorial](https://opensourceforu.com/2016/11/discovering-versatility-user-mode-linux/), using the linux-5.3.11 kernel. Following [this tutorial](https://www.hiroom2.com/2018/05/06/ubuntu-1804-bind-en/), I tried running `sudo apt-get install -y bind9`, but `apt-get` is not installed in the UML instance. So I tried to install it, as suggested in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/860381/840352), but `dpkg` is not installed.

How do I install a package in UML?

Comment: Sorry for asking is this an Ubuntu machine?

Comment: The host machine is Ubuntu 18.04. The UML is built directly from the linux kernel.